# What is the advantage of "safe write" in JetBrains IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a "safe write" option (quotes theirs, for some reason) which, on save, instead of simply updating the file, writes to a temporary file, then deletes the original, then renames the temporary file to the original's name. I hear that `vim` also does this.

I know this causes problems with programs that are watching the file. Sometimes such programs see the delete, but never see the update, for example.

But what advantages are there? [IntelliJ's docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/system-settings.html) say that there are advantages that would be lost if you turned it off. There must be some reason this option is the default.

It took me a looong time to figure out this was how intellij operated and that it was causing some chronic issues I was facing, and took me even longer to figure out it was an option I could turn off. Now that I have that option, I'd like to know if the cure is worse than the disease, so to speak.

Comment: It makes the writes atomic. Imagine you lose power while halfway through writing the new version of a file. IntelliJ's way will never store a partial write.

Comment: Couldn't you just use IntelliJ's local history to save your ass in that (very VERY unlikely) case?

Comment: Also, isn't that something that your OS kind of takes care of?

Comment: Not until after other programs have potentially already seen the bad write.

Comment: I see, well if that's the only benefit, It makes me feel a lot better about turning that feature off! Thanks! Write an answer by the way!

Comment: I gave just one trivial example of when this is a concern. There are others. I can't speak well enough on the subject to answer fully.

Comment: Fair enough. I would say that the write still isn't quite "atomic", since you have the space between the delete and the rename in which problems can happen - problems like with watchers like I mentioned.

Comment: I believe swapping out the files is done with an atomic operation, not with a delete followed by a move, though I may be wrong.

Comment: One drawback of this approach is, that the group of the file may be changed on OS like linux. A simple write preserves owners and groups, creation of a new file does not.

Comment: Another drawback of using "safe write", is that it replaces hard links by copies of the file. I have a project where the same file has to be in different locations of the source tree. I tried using hard links to avoid duplication. No good, as soon as I edit one of the references with IntelliJ (with "safe write" on), the hard link is gone.

Comment: This supposedly *safe* option has actually made me lose hours of work over the years, because it makes my Windows synchronization client, MEGAsync, blind (apparently quite randomly) to some changes.

Answer (score 12):

The safe write prevents you from data loss in case something goes wrong during the update. Just think of your computer or IntelliJ crashing while you are saving the file. You might lose the file completely then. But with safe write, you would lose your recent changes only. After the updated version of your file is written to disk without errors, the old version can be replaced. This way, you have a valid file version at any point of time during the update process, so no crash or whatever could make you lose all your work on that file. The worst thing which could happen is the loss of your recent changes.